# Usage of camerabin and camerabin2

Tags: gstreamer

I've been investigating camerabin and camerabin2 because I want to find examples to use view-finder, image-capture and video-capture properties, could you be kind to provide several examples? useful material is too rare.
Based on what I have collected, it seems hard to implement above three caps with Gstreamer command pipeline, but with Gstreamer APIs, don't know if I got it right.

Comment: per my perspective, Gstreamer Bin is used to contain several elements, link them so the whole pipeline seems more simple, am I right?

Comment: Guys, any comment? :)